# How to lift a partial function in an Either

Tags: scala

I want to lift a partial function in an `Either`.

Is there a better way :

```
def lift[A, B, C](pf : PartialFunction[A, B])(c: A => C) : A =>  Either[C, B] = { a => if (pf.isDefinedAt(a)) Right(pf(a)) else Left(c(a)) }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of other ways of writing this that let you avoid the unpleasant `isDefinedAt`:

```
def lift[A, B, C](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(c: A => C): A => Either[C, B] =
  (pf andThen Right.apply) orElse (PartialFunction(c andThen Left.apply))
```

Or:

```
def lift[A, B, C](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(c: A => C): A => Either[C, B] =
  (a: A) => pf.lift(a).fold[Either[C, B]](Left(c(a)))(Right(_))
```

For example.

Scalaz makes the last implementation above a little nicer with its `toRight`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def lift[A, B, C](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(c: A => C): A => Either[C, B] =
  (a: A) => pf.lift(a).toRight(c(a))
```

I'd probably go with some version of the `orElse` implementation, though.